# My option parsing snippet

Tags: bash, getopt

Here's a snippet that I use to parse options in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=${0##*/}
PROGVERSION=0.1
wW='-4.5.5-double'
reName=

usage()
{
  cat << EO
Script purpose goes here.
EO

  cat <<EO | column -s\& -t

  -h, --help & show this output
  -r, --rename & renames confout to Your gro
  -v, --version & show version information
  -w, --workWith & gromax exec suffix
EO
}

SHORTOPTS="hvw:r"
LONGOPTS="help,version,workWith:rename"

ARGS=$(getopt -s bash --options $SHORTOPTS --longoptions $LONGOPTS --name $PROGNAME -- "$@")

eval set -- "$ARGS"

while true; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help)
            usage; exit 0;;
        -v|--version)
            echo "$PROGVERSION"; exit 0;;
        -w|--workWith)
            wW=$2; shift;;
        -r|--rename)
            reName="true"; shift;;
        --)
            shift; break;;
        *)
            shift; break;;
    esac
    shift
done


# ====================
## finally the script:

echo "rename:" $reName
echo '    wW:' $wW
```

This snippet parses option (-w) only if it is before the trigger (-r):

```
~/wrk/mlDn/vas/res/bbst: test.bash -w 'dfdff' -r
rename: true
    wW: dfdff
~/wrk/mlDn/vas/res/bbst: test.bash -r -w 'dfdff' 
rename: true
    wW: -4.5.5-double
```

How can this be fixed? What is wrong with my snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the call to `shift` from the `-r` processing. It's removing the `-w` from `ARGS`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are shifting twice: once when you see the `-r` option and then again when you exit the `case` statement. This causes you to jump over the `-w` option. Therefore, you should only shift once. Remove the `shift` from outside the `case` statement and do all the shifting inside it.

Change your code to:

```
while true; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help)
            usage; exit 0;;
        -v|--version)
            echo "$PROGVERSION"; exit 0;;
        -w|--workWith)
            wW=$2; shift 2;; # shift twice here
        -r|--rename)
            reName="true"; shift;;
        --)
            shift; break;;
        *)
            shift; break;;
    esac
    #shift # this shift is not required
done
echo  "rename:" $reName
echo '    wW:' $wW
```